# Фильтрация с помощью django_select2

Tags: django, select2

Для заполнения формы `MyForm` с полем, содержащим имя пользователя, использую django_select2.

Для того, чтобы исключить из получившегося списка текущего пользователя я определил метод `filter_queryset` как показано ниже.

Как получить в контексте метода `filter_queryset` имя пользователя или `request`? Может есть другой способ исключить из списка текущего пользователя?

```
class UserTitleWidget(ModelSelect2Widget):
    model = User
    search_fields = [
        'username__icontains'
    ]

    def filter_queryset(self, term, queryset=None, **dependent_fields):
        # TODO fix exclude
        return queryset.exclude(username='CURRENT_USERNAME').filter(username__contains=term)


class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    value = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta:

        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
        )
        widgets = {
            'username': UserTitleWidget(),
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил с помощью добавления нового скрытого поля, значение которого соответствует текущему пользователю и выставляется автоматически. Полю с выпадающим списком пользователей добавил в зависимые поля новое поле.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.me = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Инициализация значения поля значением, соответствующим текущему ползователю
        self.fields['me'].queryset = User.objects.filter(id=self.me.id)
        self.fields['me'].initial = User.objects.get(id=self.me.id)

    me = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None) # скрытое поле

    value = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
        )
        widgets = {
            'username': UserTitleWidget(dependent_fields={'me': 'me'}),
        }
```

Значение для фильтра берутся из `dependent_fields`:

```
class UserTitleWidget(ModelSelect2Widget):
    model = User
    search_fields = [
        'username__icontains'
    ]

    def filter_queryset(self, term='', queryset=None, **dependent_fields):
        if 'me' in dependent_fields:
            return queryset.filter(username__icontains=term).exclude(id=dependent_fields['me'])
        else:
            return queryset.filter(username__icontains=term)
```

Пользователь в форму передаётся из view в методе `get_form_kwargs`:

```
class MyFormView(FormView):
    .....
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(MyFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

Ну и на фронте поле `me` имеет смысл спрятать.